# 6-Year Graduation Rates, Pell and First-Generation Students

Tags: education

I'm looking to confirm I'm using the correct variables for the following groups:

1. C150_4 = 6-year graduation rate
2. PELL_COMP_ORIG_YR6_RT = 6-year graduation rate for Pell eligible students.
3. NOPELL_COMP_ORIG_YR6_RT = 6-year graduation rate for non-Pell eligible students.
4. FIRSTGEN_COMP_ORIG_YR6_RT = 6-year graduation rate for first-generation students.
5. NOT1STGEN_COMP_ORIG_YR6_RT = 6-year graduation rate for non-first-generation students.

Thanks!